# Como inserir uma biblioteca em um projeto no Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Sou novo no desenvolvimento em aplicações para Android e achei bem legal a ideia de incrementar meus aplicativos com uma espécie de Intro assim que eles são executados.

Foi pesquisando sobre isso que eu cheguei até esta biblioteca:
https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Acontece, no entanto, que eu não estou conseguindo adicioná-la ao projeto. Já tentei declarar esta biblioteca como uma dependência no meu build.gradle, assim como o desenvolvedor explica, mas não consegui fazer com que a biblioteca fosse baixada no meu projeto no Android Studio.

Alguém pode me auxiliar fazendo um passo a passo ou tem uma sugestão mais adequada para realizar isso que eu estou perguntando?

Obrigado =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, execute seu `Android Studio` com permissões de `administrador`.

Após isso, navegue até o `build.gradle` no root de seu projeto e adicione a linha:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Logo após alterar este arquivo, uma mensagem semelhante irá aparecer no topo de seu Android Studio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em `Sync Now`.

Em seguida, vá até o `build.gradle` dentro do diretório de seu projeto (geralmente chamado **`app`**) e adicione a linha:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:2.0.0'
}
```

Após a alteração, a mensagem acima irá aparecer novamente e, mais uma vez, clique em `Sync Now`.

Desta maneira, você irá conseguir utilizar a biblioteca dentro de seu projeto.

Outra maneira de fazer o `Sync` de seus arquivos `.gradle` é através do atalho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pelas explicações, @sicachester. Eu realizei os procedimentos que você indicou mas acontece que logo na primeira alteração que você sugeriu não surgiu a mensagem no topo do Android Studio. Tentei sincronizar o projeto utilizando o atalho da imagem que você postou mas isso também não provocou nenhum efeito.

Uma coisa que deve ser mencionada é que eu criei um projeto do zero para testar as alterações que você sugeriu.

Será que preciso configurar alguma coisa do Maven no meu ambiente?

Comment: Eu executei o Android Studio com permissões administrativas e depois disso a mensagem indicando o Sync apareceu.

Agora, toda vez que eu eu altero alguma coisa nos arquivos .gradle eu realizo o Sync, assim como você me indicou.

Mas me responda uma coisa: esta sincronização não deveria baixar os arquivos para o meu projeto? A estrutura de arquivos parece não ter sido alterada mesmo após ter realizado o sync várias vezes. Os arquivos da biblioteca que eu mencionei deveriam aparecer no Project ou isso é uma viagem minha?

Comment: @SpammingOff após você adicionar a dependencia dentro do seu `build.gradle` e realizar o `Sync`, ele irá baixar no último package chamado `External Libraries`. Lá dentro irá aparecer a dependencia junto com as outras já importadas de seu projeto (como o SDK do Android etc)

Comment: Ah cara... Verdade. Agora eu preciso aprender a usar essa biblioteca =)

Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda!